# Steam won't launch my games...Ubuntu 15.04 x64

Tags: steam

After I press Play for War thunder this is what I get in the terminal.

```
WarThunder Updater version 1.0.7
Looking for a new version...
Checking game version... 
Checking files... 100%
Running /home/sean/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/War Thunder/aces
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/sean/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 236390
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198131518133 [API loaded no]
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/sean/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Critical error

Videomode initialization error. [8111000B]

Visit <a href=https://support.gaijin.net/hc/en-us/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/sean/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

I also press Play on Besiege and a small window says preparing to launch Besiege and nothing happens after that.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue similar to this not so long ago on another system. The only way we could get the thing to work was to delete most of the files in the Steam folder and then download them again. If you do try this, make sure you do a backup first though.

Answer (score 0):

I had Steam issues with an older Ubuntu build and disabling the Steam overlay resolved them. That bug very well may have been resolved since then as it was some time ago.

Not that it helps, but I think it was running through [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/about/) when I experienced that.

Comment: What exactly is WINE?

Comment: Wine is an emulator that allows to use some of Windows softwares that have `.exe` and alike formats and play games too.